# Angular CRUD Delete needs a suscribe inside a Suscribe defined in GetAll

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, json-server

I'm trying to do a CRUD using json-server and Angular Material, So I have my service:

Service

```
  borrarPago(id: Number):Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>('api/pagos/'+id)
  }

  traerPagos():Observable<Pago[]>{   
    return this.http.get<Pago[]>('api/pagos');
  }
```

And this is my component consuming my service:

```
  refrescar(data:Pago[]) {
    this.listaPagos = data;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Pago>(data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
  }

  borrarPago(id:Number):void {
    this._pagoService.borrarPago(id)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this._pagoService.traerPagos()
    });
    
  }

  traerPagos(): void {
    this._pagoService.traerPagos()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.refrescar(data);
    });
  }
```

---

**Problem:** What is happening is that, when I delete an item, the item is deleted but the material table is not refreshed.

**What I tried:** I put a subscribe inside a subscribe inside `borrarPago()` method, this is the only way it works, but that seems redundant as `traerPagos()` already subscribes.

**Other article/s I read:** Is there any other way for this to work? I was also following this article, but the person is using the same logic, where inside the delete method he calls the getAll method without another subscribe (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-11-curd-application-using-web-api-with-material-design/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'subscribe inside a subscribe' is not working because it is not firing.

```
 borrarPago(id:Number):void {
    this._pagoService.borrarPago(id)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this._pagoService.traerPagos()
    });
    
  }

  traerPagos(): void {
    this._pagoService.traerPagos()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.refrescar(data);
    });
  }
```

In the code above, when your code hits this._pagoService.traerPagos(), it's not calling your refrescar function.

```
 borrarPago(id:Number):void {
    this._pagoService.borrarPago(id)
    .subscribe(() => {
// here you should call your COMPONENT's traerPagos() function instead of your SERVICE'S traerPagos() function,
      this.traerPagos()
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: Crap... you are right. Now... is this a correct implementation? to have nested functions inside the suscribe events to keep things updated? or is there a "correct" way to implement a certain design pattern for this?

Comment: It works and is unsubscribing since this observable is self completing, but it is best practice to use an Rxjs operator to flatten your subscription using exhaustMap, switchMap, or concatMap

Comment: The 'subscribe inside a subscribe' is not uncommon, this usually happens when you need to chain HTTP request that are dependent on another HTTP request. In your case, your implementation should work if that is really the flow that you need

Answer (score 0):

Try using a switchMap inside. This will manage your inner subscriptions by unsubscribing then resubscribing under the hood in Rxjs.

```
borrarPago(id:Number):void {
this._pagoService.borrarPago(id)
.pipe(switchMap(() => {
   return this._pagoService.traerPagos()
 })
.subscribe(data => {
  this.refrescar(data);
});
```

}

Comment: It says Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: this._pagoService.traerPagos() Would need to be returning an observable and not void.